# HTML unique ids with jQuery - a better way to solve this

Tags: jquery, html

So I use this nice little widget to create tabs but my editor is complaining that it's not valid and according to the spec that is true.  As you can see I have two id's named the same.   My question is what is a correct way to fix this?

Here is the html

```
<ul id="tabs">
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" name="tab1">Stuff</a></li>
    {% if not is_passing %}
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" name="tab2">More Stuff</a></li>
    {% endif %}
</ul>

<div id="panes">
    <div id="tab1">Tab 1</div>
    <div id="tab2">Tab 2</div>
</div>

<script style="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#panes").children("div").hide();         // Initially hide all content
        $("#tabs li:first").attr("id","current");   // Activate first tab
        $("#panes div:first").fadeIn();             // Show first tab content

        $('#tabs a').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if ($(this).closest("li").attr("id") == "current"){ //detection for current tab
                return false;
            }
            else{
                $("#panes").children("div").hide();     //Hide all content
                $("#tabs li").attr("id","");            //Reset id's
                $(this).parent().attr("id","current");  // Activate this
                $('#' + $(this).attr('name')).fadeIn(); // Show content for current tab
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: The way to fix it is to only use unique ID's, and never use the same ID more than once in a document.

Comment: Agreed - but that clearly will break the jquery.  The id is being used to turn on/off the tabs..

Comment: I dont get why you cant use unique id's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues here:

1. Using `#current` on tabs and tab contents
2. Having tab name attribute and tab content id the same

Use a class for current instead of an id

Use `addClass`, `removeClass` and `hasClass`

Of course you'll have to change your CSS from `#current` to `.current`

And use rel instead of name.

```
<ul id="tabs">
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" rel="tab1">Stuff</a></li>
    {% if not is_passing %}
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" rel="tab2">More Stuff</a></li>
    {% endif %}
</ul>

<div id="panes">
    <div id="tab1">Tab 1</div>
    <div id="tab2">Tab 2</div>
</div>


<script style="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#panes").children("div").hide();         // Initially hide all content
        $("#tabs li:first").addClass("current");   // Activate first tab
        $("#panes div:first").fadeIn();             // Show first tab content

        $('#tabs a').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if ($(this).closest("li").hasClass("current")){ //detection for current tab
                return false;
            }
            else{
                $("#panes").children("div").hide();     //Hide all content
                $("#tabs li").removeClass("current");            //Reset
                $(this).parent().addClass("current");  // Activate this
                $('#' + $(this).attr('rel')).fadeIn(); // Show content for current tab
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You need to do better than that - example please.

Comment: Nice work.  Can you explain how this solves the id problem.  Do I remove the id="Tab1" altogether?  If so how does the relationship happen?

Comment: I've just made it so that you don't have multiple #current which is not allowed, but rather .current which is ok. You will still need #tab1 etc.

Comment: OK - but that didn't actually fix the problem?  I still have a name=tab1 and and id=tab1 which means that I still have the error?  id==name.  Maybe I'm missing something?  FWIW - 'duplicate or unresolved ID'

Comment: That dramatically simplified the problem..  Basically change name to rel.  Changing of 'current' is not needed.  Thanks!!

Comment: Changing current is needed too, even if you're editor doesn't complain because if you see the source as you click tabs you will see the link and the tab content div will both have #current which is invalid and could cause issues.